# jQuery-AJAX: the focusout event is fired twice

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple HTML form:

```
<form id="contactForm" method="post" action="./validateForm.php">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Vorname</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="firstName" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Nachname</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="surname" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>E-Mail</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="eMail" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alter</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="age" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </form>
```

I have this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function validationResult(objData, strStatus, objXMLHttpRequest) {

      if('error' === objXMLHttpRequest.responseText)
        alert('error');
      else
        alert('success');

    }

    $('#contactForm input').focusout(function() {

      var strLeftField      = $(this).attr('name');
      var strLeftFieldValue = $('input [name=' + strLeftField + ']').val();

      $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: './validateForm.php', data: strLeftField=strLeftFieldValue, async: true, cache: false, success: validationResult });

    });

  });
```

I am wondering why the .focusout() event is fireing twice. It must have something to do with the AJAX request, because if I comment it out, it is not fireing twice. But why?

Is the focusout() event even the right event to determine if the user has left an input field in my form?

I am using jquery-2.0.3.min.js if this is relevant.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Best regards.

Comment: Check this link maybe https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117307.
Not the answer but you can get the value directly using $(this).val().

Comment: Yes, you're totally right.
I also observed, if I tab/click from an input field to the next, the POST request is fired twice, but when I click instead to the next input filed to "out" of the form, it is only fired once.
Also when I replace the focusout() with change() the POST request is made once.

Comment: you are binding all inputs in #contactForm. so focusOut of every input will cause ajax request. on ajax success you are calling validationResult function. this function shows alert in both parts of if condition. Alert is causing focusOut again. When alert is closed then previously focused control will again get focus. So, I think it is not firing twice, but must be firing infinitely.